# Mono runtime error when loading MVC app using XSP

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mono

I've recently taken a stab at developing some classes and contributing to the mono project. Its actually not as tough as I was expecting it to be.... but I've got an issue that just suddenly appeared after a few local builds.... the following comes from the xsp server:

``` An exception has occurred while generating HttpException page:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.GetCustomEncoderFromConfig () [0x00006] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Util/HttpEncoder.cs:194 
  at System.Lazy``1[System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder].InitValue () [0x0015f] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/corlib/System/Lazy.cs:164 ```

followed by:

`The actual exception which was being reported was:
System.Web.HttpException: Initial exception ---> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime..cctor () [0x00051] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpRuntime.cs:138 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---`

I can see that this code is the following line: 
`runtime_section = (HttpRuntimeSection) WebConfigurationManager.GetSection ("system.web/httpRuntime");`

So the cast is failing... I assume I have some errant assembly lying around somewhere but really can't find it.

This seems to be happening on any new MVC projects and ones that were working prior as well.

Any suggestions?